# Should non-trainable functions be part of a nn model?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Some explanation for the somewhat obscure title:

I want to train a model which can produce images given some input data. However, actually I want the model to learn some abstract representation which I can input into a rendering function which in turn should produce the actual image.

My question is now whether the rendering functions should be part of the models `forward()` function? On the one hand nothing in there will be trainable, on the other hand I guess it will be used for calculating the loss (using pytorch):

```
def train(
    model: CustomModel, optimizer: Optimizer, loss_function: MSELoss, dataset: SceneDataset
) -> float:
    model.train()

    inputs, labels = next(dataset)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(inputs)

    loss = loss_function(outputs, labels) # label is a image here
    loss.backward()

    return loss.item()
```

How is this kind of issue usually dealt with?

Comment: Can you add more detail about this rendering function? It would be differentiable operations so gradient could still be computed after the image is constructed? Or is it a black-box?

Comment: @GiovanniAmorim yes the rendering function ought to be differentiable in order to be usable in the training process  right?

Comment: Yes, it must be differentiable if you want to use the some error applied directly to the image and compute grandients. If that is the case I don't see any problem in implementing the forward method with the application of this rendering function. If it was not differentiable maybe a reinforcement learning approach could work as well but that is a whole other conversation.

Comment: Just for completeness sake - in case it would not be differentiable (I'm sure in my case it is, but just for a general case), I would have to be able to calculate back from my target-label to the expected representation parameters for the model output, right? Additionally it would have to be separate to the forward function.

Comment: If you can only judge the output from the generated image, yes. If you are able to compute some kind of loss from the final trainable output directly, even if it uses values from the rendering process, you could apply it without the back calculation. And there are other ways, like if it is some kind of classification task instead (I understand the final task you are performing is the image construction), you could use RL algortihms to just signal "good" or "bad" classifications to your model.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the additional explanation  :)